# I am unable to find few packages when I'm trying to run the AutoCkt file which is available on GitHub

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

These are the list of packages that I'm unable to find. I'm using windows and trying to run this github code in gitbash.

[here](https://github.com/ksettaluri6/AutoCkt) is the link for the code

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libopus
  - ncurses
  - libvpx
  - dbus
  - libedit
  - readline
  - libuuid
```

I have tried deleting the version of the packages that were missing but it worked in few cases and the one's in which I couldn't find anything are those which are listed above.

The original version of the packages are listed in the github in `environment.yml` file.